# PHP string value to int value if statement

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have a little issue I've been cracking my head over.

I have a variable $mode that is a string. It can have either of these 2 values
light & normal

Now I want to send this value in my response as an int (not a boolean)
If the value is light it should be 0 and if it's normal it should be 1

Now I have done this with an if but it just doesn't seem so clean is there perhaps a better way to do this?

My code:

```
if ($mode == 'light') {
    $mode = 0;
} elseif ($mode == 'normal') {
    $mode = 1;
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: use true and false instead of 1 and 0

Comment: @kashif I don't want it to be a boolean because it van also be 2 in an other case

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with 1 and 0 ? can u brief ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
<?php
  $mode = 'light';
  $mode = ($mode == 'light' ? 0 : 1);
  echo $mode; // returns 0 for light and 1 for other
?>
```

Comment: what if it's 'normal'?

Comment: returns 1 for normal

Comment: there was a mistake in my code before...i have edited it now...ppls check

Comment: This function will return 1 also for  values like `norman` , `Light` or `ligth` is this your intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Why not using an `array` instead? This could help -

```
$response = array(
    'light' => 0,
    'normal' => 1,
    'other' => 2,
);

echo $response[$mode];
```

If `$mode` may have any other value then they can be added to the array or some checks can be used. like -

```
echo (isset($response[$mode])) ? $response[$mode] : 'other value';
```